# How to move a file from windows workstation to a windows VM using python

Tags: python, ssh, virtual-machine

I am trying to move a file from my local box to my VM using Python but I can't due to ssh error stating it can't connect. That makes sense as I don't have sshd installed on the VM yet.

It seems like my next step is to get ssh install onto my VM but I'm not sure how as I don't know how to move a file from the workstation to the VM. Any advice is appreciated.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["scp","/desktop/test.txt","<user>@<PC‌​‌​-name>:\<PC-name>\‌​C$‌​\user\<user>\des‌​ktop‌​\test.txt"])
```

Comment: import subprocess 

subprocess.check_call(["scp","/desktop/test.txt","<user>@<PC‌​-name>:\<PC-name>\C$‌​\user\<user>\desktop‌​\test.txt"])

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with working with virtual machines! I thought `os.system` would help even though it is depreciated as it is what I would use for something similar.